# How can we use deprecated apex class again in the managed package?

Tags: apex, managed-package, rollback, solutions, deprecated

Is there any way by which we can use the deprecated apex class again in the managed package?

Comment: You simply cannot. If it is a 2GP and it was only just deprecated, and customers don't have the later version(s) installed, you could branch off a new version tree from before that deprecation.

Comment: Can you help me guiding how can I branch off a new version tree from before deprecation one?

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_config_ancestors.htm#!